# как создать функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

У меня есть вот такой повторяющийся код. меняются там только первые две строки, остальное повторяется много раз и получается портянка. Вот код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    button_push = callback_query
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
    print(button_push.data)
    push = button_push.data
    button_request = config.switch_button.get(push)
    print(button_request)
    con = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', password='', database='testop')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(button_request)
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        print(rows)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows)
```

как сделать функцию из нижеследующего куска?

```
 button_push = callback_query
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
    print(button_push.data)
    push = button_push.data
    button_request = config.switch_button.get(push)
    print(button_request)
    con = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', password='', database='testop')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(button_request)
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        print(rows)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows)
```

---

@ Интик Отвечу тут.
Вот сделал так например:

```
def buttons(callback_query):
        button_push = callback_query
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
        print(button_push.data)
        push = button_push.data
        button_request = config.switch_button.get(push)
        print(button_request)
        con = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', password='', database='')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(button_request)
            rows = cur.fetchone()
            print(rows)
            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows)
            return rows
```

вот так стартую:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
connects_db.buttons()
```

И получаю вот такой эррор:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chat_for_site/bot.py", line 6, in <module>
    import connects_db
  File "/Users/chat_for_site/connects_db.py", line 20
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

Но import connects_db стоит и работает при портянке

Comment: Ну вот то, что повторяется, соберите в отдельную функцию и вызывайте её

Comment: @ CrazyElf вот это и не получается. покажете?

Comment: покажите ваши попытки которые не получаются. и полный текст ошибок при этом.  попробуйте начать с прочтения https://pythonru.com/osnovy/funkcii-v-python

Comment: `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function` буквально означает, что await должно быть внутри асинхронной функции, т.е. как минимум должно быть `async def buttons(callback_query)`

Answer (score 0):

Вот. Нашел решение. Может кому сгодится:

```
allow_buttons = [f"button{i}" for i in range(1, 10)]


 @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in allow_buttons)
 async def process_callback_button(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
     button_push = callback_query
     await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
     print(button_push.data)
     push = button_push.data
     button_request = config.switch_button.get(push)
     print(button_request)
     rows = sql_query(button_request)
     await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows, reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
```

а так же запрос к базе вынес в функцию:

```
def sql_query(query):
    con = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', password='', database='')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        print(rows)
        return rows
```